# how do I delete text after last period

Tags: string, sed, grep, geektool

I am using Nerdtool on and iMac running OSx 10.6.8 and have written some code to get a weather report and display it on my desktop. How do I delete the text after the last period beginning with "Forcast issued"? A second issue I noticed is that the text returned has a 'space' in front of the first character. I'd like that gone too.
Below is the command and output I get using Terminal.
Thanks.

Command:

```
curl --silent "http://weather.gc.ca/rss/city/on-137_e.xml" | grep -E '(Weather Forecasts:|</summary)'| head -3 | sed -e 's/<summary type=\"html\">//' -e 's/<\/summary>//' -e 's/]]> //' -e 's/No watches or warnings in effect. //'
```

Output:

> Sunny this morning then a mix of sun and cloud with 40 percent chance of showers this afternoon. Risk of a thunderstorm this afternoon. Wind becoming west 20 km/h this afternoon. High 29. UV index 8 or very high. Forecast issued 05:00 AM EDT Friday 31 July 2015

Comment: this is very broad. Provide a representative sample input, define clearly what is your desired output and show -also clearly- what you tried. You may want to read [ask].

Comment: You may also want to see, "What should I do when someone answers my question?": http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @fedorqui. I think I clearly stated what my goals where, providing both my code and the output produced by it. The quick and accurate reply by nathan I think supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to use `sed s` to delete text. You can target the front of the line with `^` and the end of the line with `$`. So you can delete the space at the beginning with:
`-e 's/^ //'`
And delete `Forecast issued` to the end of the line with:
`-e 's/ Forecast issued.*$//'`